# How to get sum of unique items from current and previous rows but ignore repeating items Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How to write a query in *Oracle SQL* to get from the table I have to the table I want as below:

What I have:

```
Date            Item        Units
-----------     --------    --------
05-NOV-2018     A           3
05-NOV-2018     E           4
09-NOV-2018     C           7
16-NOV-2018     B           9
16-NOV-2018     D           4
21-NOV-2018     A           5
29-NOV-2018     B           12
29-NOV-2018     C           10
29-NOV-2018     F           6
29-NOV-2018     A           8
```

What I want:

```
Date            Total_Units_Per_Day
-----------     --------------------
05-NOV-2018     7
09-NOV-2018     14
16-NOV-2018     27
21-NOV-2018     29
29-NOV-2018     44
```

How the Total_Units_Per_Day column was calculated:

```
Date            Item        Units       Total_Unique_Items_Accumulated_Per_Day      Total_Units_Per_Day
-----------     --------    --------    -------------------------------             --------------------
05-NOV-2018     A           3           A, E                                        7
05-NOV-2018     E           4           A, E                                        7
09-NOV-2018     C           7           A, E, C                                     14
16-NOV-2018     B           9           A, E, C, B, D                               27
16-NOV-2018     D           4           A, E, C, B, D                               27
21-NOV-2018     A           5           A, E, C, B, D                               29
29-NOV-2018     B           12          A, E, C, B, D, F                            44
29-NOV-2018     C           10          A, E, C, B, D, F                            44
29-NOV-2018     F           6           A, E, C, B, D, F                            44
29-NOV-2018     A           8           A, E, C, B, D, F                            44
```

As we progress through each day (from 5th to 29th Nov 2018), sum the units of each item in that day and all the previous day. **However**, do not take into account the units of the item from the previous(s) day if it is already present in the current day.

For example on 21th Nov 2018, *Total_Units_Per_Day = 29*. This is done by summing the units of all the previous items **but** use:

*A=5 units from (21th Nov 2018) instead of A=3 units from (5th Nov 2018)*

Is this type of query possible? Any help would be appreciated (: Thanks!

Comment: @GordonLinoff my mistake, let me fix that

Comment: How many different items do you have?

Comment: @GordonLinoff the amount of different items would increase (not fixed)

Comment: . . By the way, this is one of the most interesting questions I've encountered in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite complicated.  You seem to want the most recent value for each item.

If you have a finite list of items, then you can take a brute force approach:

```
select dte, 
       (lag(case when item = 'A' then units end ignore nulls, 1, 0) over (order by dte) +
        lag(case when item = 'B' then units end ignore nulls, 1, 0) over (order by dte) +
        lag(case when item = 'C' then units end ignore nulls, 1, 0) over (order by dte) +
        lag(case when item = 'D' then units end ignore nulls, 1, 0) over (order by dte) +
        lag(case when item = 'E' then units end ignore nulls, 1, 0) over (order by dte) +
        lag(case when item = 'F' then units end ignore nulls, 1, 0) over (order by dte) 
       ) as total_units_per_day
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3b9f05ef031172c80b91a0bf3ca4d184) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

Here is a more general approach:

```
select dte, sum(units) as total_units_per_day
from (select d.dte, t.item, t.units, row_number() over (partition by t.item, d.dte order by t.dte desc) as seqnum
      from (select distinct dte from t) d join
           t
           on t.dte <= d.dte
    ) td 
where seqnum = 1
group by dte
order by dte;
```

And a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ccaf90f75cc4ef894238535a2910e3a0) for this.

Comment: @doe . . . I think it is correct:  A/8, B/12, C/10, D/4, E/4, F/6.  That is 44, not 50.

Comment: the general approach works well ! you're amazing, thanks a bunch !

Comment: yes I've just realised, its my fault! thanks ! (I deleted the comment that Gordon was replying to in his answer. The comment was I thought the code didn't take into account F, but I miss read and Gordon's code is right)

Answer (score 0):

This would be the classical aprpoach to solve your problem:
Simple sum the units per day and than calculate the cummulative sum using analytic function.

```
with tot as (
select trans_date, sum(units) total_unit 
from tab
group by trans_date)
select trans_date, 
sum(total_unit) over (order by trans_date) total_unit_cum
from tot
order by 1 
;

TRANS_DATE          TOTAL_UNIT_CUM
------------------- --------------
05.11.2018 00:00:00              7
09.11.2018 00:00:00             14
16.11.2018 00:00:00             27
21.11.2018 00:00:00             32
29.11.2018 00:00:00             68
```

But this provides a higher results that expected.
The reason is that within a `item` your `units`  are already cummulated.

So in the first step *clean up the units* and calculate the *real delta value*
by subtracting the `LAG` value - from previous record, with default zero - `lag(units,1,0) ...`

```
select 
trans_date, item, units units_orig,
units - lag(units,1,0) over (partition by item order by trans_date) units
from tab
order by 1,2;

TRANS_DATE          I UNITS_ORIG       UNITS
------------------- - ---------- ----------
05.11.2018 00:00:00 A          3          3
05.11.2018 00:00:00 E          4          4
09.11.2018 00:00:00 C          7          7
16.11.2018 00:00:00 B          9          9
16.11.2018 00:00:00 D          4          4
21.11.2018 00:00:00 A          5          2
29.11.2018 00:00:00 A          8          3
29.11.2018 00:00:00 B         12          3
29.11.2018 00:00:00 C         10          3
29.11.2018 00:00:00 F          6          6
```

Finaly simple combine the both queries

```
with clean as (
select 
trans_date, item, units units_orig,
units - lag(units,1,0) over (partition by item order by trans_date) units
from tab),
tot as (
select trans_date, sum(units) total_unit 
from clean
group by trans_date)
select trans_date, 
sum(total_unit) over (order by trans_date) total_unit_cum
from tot
order by 1 
;

TRANS_DATE          TOTAL_UNIT_CUM
------------------- --------------
05.11.2018 00:00:00              7
09.11.2018 00:00:00             14
16.11.2018 00:00:00             27
21.11.2018 00:00:00             29
29.11.2018 00:00:00             44
```

This is not the shorted possible query, but is simple to understand...